# Using specific array count

Tags: c#

My array max size is 20. If I were to enter data that would be less than 20,how do I get it where my program only counts the used arrays?

```
for (int i = 0; i < Score.Length; i++)
{
    sum = sum + Score[i];

}
average = sum / Score.Length;
```

If I use this for loop above, it always divides by 20 for the average. I need it to only count the ones I entered, not 20.  *I would prefer solutions using arrays*

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a `List<T>` rather than an array - that way you don't need to specify the size up-front.

Comment: You need to keep track of how many items you add in a separate variable. If you want to have this done for you, then use a [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead.

Comment: in that case use `List<int>` rather

Answer (score 0):

If you insist in using arrays, then you must keep track of how many items you added to the array, like:

```
int[] Score = new int[20];
Random rdn = new Random();

int size=0;
for(int i=0;i<rdn.Next(0,20);i++)
{
    Score[i] = rdn.Next();
    size++;
}

int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    sum = sum + Score[i];

}
double average = sum / size;
```

A better option is to use the `List` class that keep track for you of the number of items you add

```
List<int> Score = new List<int>();
Random rdn = new Random();


for(int i=0;i<rdn.Next(0,20);i++)
{
    Score.Add(rdn.Next());
}

int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < Score.Count; i++)
{
    sum = sum + Score[i];
}
double average = sum / Score.Count;
```

And of course, as you didn't say the type of your data you could use other data types, like double, float, long, decimal for both solutions.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably an overkill, but another approach would be to use a `SparseVector` class of the **Math.Numerics** package:

Sparse Vector uses two arrays which are usually much shorter than the vector. One array stores all values that are not zero, the other stores their indices.

> PM > Install-Package MathNet.Numerics

```
var vector = SparseVector.Build.SparseOfArray(Score);
var sum = vector.Sum();
```

`Sum()` will only go through non-empty elements.

Answer (score -1):

You need to keep track of the record that are `!= 0`, so

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if ( array[i] != 0 ) 
    { 
        count++;
        sum += array[i];
    }
}
average = sum / count;
```

And beware of division by 0 ;)

Comment: OP doesn't say that the valid items are positive. He wants to know the used range of the array, so he need a variable to keep the count at the time the array was filled, not at the time of the sum.

Comment: @Magnetron what values hold an empty array of integers?

Comment: Anyway, edited to count occurrences of used elements instead of just positive ones

Comment: Althought the default value for integers is zero, you can't tell if a zero value is because the item of the array is undefined by the user or if the user set it's value for zero. So if the array is [1,2,0,3,4,...] or [1,2,-1,3,4,...] your code will fail.

Comment: The edit is still wrong because for an array of int or double, can't have null items

Comment: Uhm... right. Maybe converting the array in a string array, but it’s way too hacky and error-prone

Comment: You *could* use an array of nullable integers (`int?[]`) but that seems like just adding a lot of unnecessary complexity compared to a `List<int>`